# Caching mostly static pages

Tags: http, caching

I have a website with quite a few pages that are *mostly* static, in that the contents of the page are static but there are a couple of general links that change depending on whether the client is logged in (the usual stuff; login link vs. account settings &c).

Are there any established conventions for handling caching of such pages? My initial thought has been to use an ordinary `Last-Modified` header, that I set to either the file's `mtime` or the last time the user's login information in the session changed, if there is any. I'm not sure how that interacts with any potential proxies or if it has any other consequences that I don't see right now.